# MoveIt and ROS-Industrial: No controller_list specified

Tags: ros, moveit, kuka, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to control my KUKA Agilus with the ROS-I experimental package and MoveIt and i get an error for no controller_list specified.

```
[ERROR] [1466689198.911826798]: No controller_list specified.
[ INFO] [1466689198.911892610]: Returned 0 controllers in list
[ INFO] [1466689198.919276819]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
```

However, i do explicitly load the yaml config:

```
controller_list:
  - name: ""
    action_ns: joint_trajectory_action
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints: [joint_a1, joint_a2, joint_a3, joint_a4, joint_a5, joint_a6]
```

And i can list the configuration with:

```
$ rosparam get /controller_list
```

What am i missing? The test XML reads as follows:

```
<launch>

  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find kuka_rsi_hw_interface)/config/controller_joint_names.yaml"/>
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find agil_moveit_config)/config/controllers.yaml"/>
  
  <arg name="sim" default="true" />
  <arg name="robot_ip" unless="$(arg sim)" />
 
  <include file="$(find agil_moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch" >
    <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true" />
  </include>

  <!-- remap topics to conform to ROS-I specifications -->
  <remap from="/position_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory" to="/joint_trajectory_action" />
  <remap from="/position_trajectory_controller/state" to="/feedback_states" />
  <remap from="/position_trajectory_controller/command" to="/joint_path_command"/>

  <!-- run the robot simulator and action interface nodes -->
  <group if="$(arg sim)">
    <include file="$(find industrial_robot_simulator)/launch/robot_interface_simulator.launch" />
    <include file="$(find kuka_rsi_hw_interface)/test/test_hardware_interface.launch" />
  </group>

  <include file="$(find agil_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch">
      <arg name="publish_monitored_planning_scene" value="true" />
  </include>

  <include file="$(find agil_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
    <arg name="config" value="true"/>
  </include>
  
  <include file="$(find agil_moveit_config)/launch/default_warehouse_db.launch" />

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237894/moveit-and-ros-industrial:-no-controller_list-specified./) by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your error message, I think you forgot to update the `agil_moveit_config/launch/kuka_kr6r900sixx_moveit_controller_manager.launch` file. That is the file that actually uploads the contents of the `config/controller.yaml` file, and sets the `moveit_controller_manager` to the correct value.

Without that, MoveIt won't know how to interface with your controllers.

---

I've also just created an example MoveIt configuration package for the KR 6 R900 sixx, see the [kr6r900sixx_moveit_rsi_convenience](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/kuka_experimental/tree/kr6r900sixx_moveit_rsi_convenience) in my fork of `ros-industrial/kuka_experimental`. I've added a bit more than just a working configuration, so please test it out and let me know if it works for you.

The main issue is that the `kuka_rsi_hw_interface` doesn't (by default) setup all the topics and services that the tutorial you followed to create your MoveIt configuration expects. Especially the namespacing of the action server and naming of the joint state and feedback topics is different. The structure I set up in [kr6r900sixx_moveit_rsi_convenience](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/kuka_experimental/tree/kr6r900sixx_moveit_rsi_convenience) takes care of that, so everything 'above' `kuka_kr6_support` should now be able to interact with the RSI `hardware_interface` as it would with a regular ROS-Industrial driver (but see also the comments in the launch files).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on 2016-06-28**:
Thanks a lot for all your effort! The simulation now works as expected. The default RRT planner now also solves the problem of the robot's weird floating behavior when executing a trajectory.However, I tried to connect the real robot with the RSI interface and there seems to be be a problem.

**Comment by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on 2016-06-28**:
Maybe it is just a minor spelling error. Executing the "rsi_axis_correction.src" on the KUKA controller yields: "File not found: rsi_axis_correction". When i change the line to load "rsi_axis_corr.rsi", it says "RSI_CREATE: File not found ETHERNET1". Do i have to remap or specify something?

**Comment by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on 2016-06-29**:
after some analysis i suppose the ETHERNET1 block in the RSI diagramm has no input source, could be the problem

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-29**:
@cschindlbeck: could you please report this to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/issues)? That way we can make sure to capture the problem and eventual solution in the proper place.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-29**:
Also: it sounds like your initial problem with the `controller_list` parameter has been resolved. Could I ask you to mark this question as solved then? The RSI / controller setup problems are unrelated to that.